# How to draw multiple segments overlapping and non overlapping in high-charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am working on visualisation of data points which has some overlapping fragments also. I found similar post here

[HighCharts: draw multiple segments in a single serie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408027/highcharts-draw-multiple-segments-in-a-single-serie)

but above example shows overlap fragment only.

**points (x-value)**

```
start   end
11874   14409
14362   29370
34611   36081
52352   53495
62915   63984
69091   70008
87523   90233
128515  133564
133661  139667
137848  144331
```

In my case, all fragments will be linear (all fragments are having fixed value of y except for overlapping segment as they should lie above to show that there is an overlap).  How this can be implemented automatically (not manually setting value of y)?

Answer (score 2):

You can set different widths of lines.
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24qf98xL/9/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        series: [{
            id: 'main',
            data: [{x: 5, y: 10}, 
                   {x: 7, y: 10}]
        }, {
            data: [{x: 2, y: 12}, 
                   {x: 9, y: 12}],
            lineWidth: 10,
            linkedTo: 'main'
        }, {
            data: [{x: 6, y: 12}, 
                   {x: 19,y: 12}],
            lineWidth: 6,
            linkedTo: 'main'
        }, {
            data: [{x: 4, y: 12}, 
                   {x: 10,y: 12}],
            linkedTo: 'main'
        }]  
    }); 
});
```

Or alternatively you can try `columnrange` type series
jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tjcg60p4/

Comment: partial overlap are also in same line while is should be at different height. That i can be done by setting value of y. But pblm is i am doing it dynamically (reading data points from file). So how can i check weather there is overlap or not?